# Latin characters in a gnome terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

In vi I type latin-1 characters like ö by doing ctlr-k o:

Can one do something like this in a gnome terminal?

Comment: i am from germany and we often use those characters. never had problems in the terminal? neither in KDE nor in Gnome2/3/mate/cinnamon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In X you can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and enter the hex code for `ö`, which is `f6`, see [the extended ASCII-table](http://www.ascii-code.com/). It also allows for 4-bytes UTF to be inputted.

**Edit**
You can also use the compose key, in Ubuntu the default is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>, and do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> followed by <kbd>o</kbd>.